# Celery worker in python3 has high number of unacknowledged messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, supervisord

We are in the process of migrating to python3. As part of our migration we are migrating celery worker on each queue one by one in production.
We use a rabbitmq broker for celery.

In python2, we run a celery worker with concurrency 40 working on multiple queues(the queue mentioned below being one of them). The number of unacked jobs almost never crosses 10 and even when it does it comes down in a few seconds.

In python3 we run a celery worker with concurrency 40 working only on a single queue. The number of unacked jobs keeps piling up here and reaches the prefetch count easily. We also checked the logs of the particular tasks in both machines. The count of tasks in python3 was always way lesser than in python2, but the duration of each task was equivalent.

We use supervisord to run these jobs.

Python 2 command :

```
celery worker -A celery_worker.app -Q q1,q2,q3,q4,q5 -c 40 --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

Python2 packages

```
celery==4.1.1
billiard==3.5.0.4
amqp==2.3.2
kombu==4.2.1
pytz==2018.7
```

Python2 celery config

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
BROKER_URL = <rabbitmqhosts>
CELERY_IMPORTS = (modules)
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = None
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
```

Python2 machine configurations

```
Ec2 instance type : r4.2xlarge
OS : Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
```

Python3 packages

```
celery==5.0.5
billiard==3.6.3.0
amqp==5.0.5
kombu==5.0.2
pytz==2021.1
```

Python 3 command :

```
celery -A celery_worker.app worker -Q q1 -c 40 --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

Python3 celery config

```
worker_hijack_root_logger = False
broker_url = <rabbitmqhosts>
imports = (modules)
broker_heartbeat = None
broker_pool_limit = 1
worker_send_task_events = False
result_backend = None
```

Python3 machine configurations

```
Ec2 instance type : c5.2xlarge
OS : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

As a workaround we had concurrency set as 1 (-c 1) in python3 with numprocs using supervisor as 40. In this case there were a good number of jobs being processed by the python3 instance, based from the logs. But this has other repercussions like high cpu usage since each celeryd process creates 1+number of concurrent processes and we also think we would not be able to pool queues together in this case.

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you so sure that it's related to the python upgrade and not the celery upgrade? why are you not splitting it into two phases? first, upgrade to python3 with celery 4.1.1 and after that try to upgrade to celery 5.0.5